# Complete a type of data

Tags: c++, c, class, unions

How should I define `FundamentalOperationalData`?  What is `FundamentalOperationalData_MarkXTransponder m_FODSystemMarkTransponder;`?  Is another data to fill inside `FundamentalOperationalData` or it is something different?
As I can see [here](http://kdis.sourceforge.net/classdoc/class_k_d_i_s_1_1_d_a_t_a___t_y_p_e_1_1_fundamental_operational_data.html) is the father.

I want to declare something as FundamentalOperationalData Mydata(1,2,3...

The source is [here](http://kdis.sourceforge.net/classdoc/_fundamental_operational_data_8h_source.html)

```
namespace KDIS {
namespace DATA_TYPE {

class KDIS_EXPORT FundamentalOperationalData : public DataTypeBase
{
protected:

    union
    {
        struct
        {
            KUINT8 m_ui8SystemStatus;
            KUINT8 m_ui8AltParam4;
            KUINT8 m_ui8InfoLayers;
            KUINT8 m_ui8Modifier;
            KUINT16 m_ui16Param1;
            KUINT16 m_ui16Param2;
            KUINT16 m_ui16Param3;
            KUINT16 m_ui16Param4;
            KUINT16 m_ui16Param5;
            KUINT16 m_ui16Param6;
        };

        FundamentalOperationalData_MarkXTransponder m_FODSystemMarkTransponder;
        FundamentalOperationalData_MarkXInterrogator m_FODSystemMarkInterrogator;
        FundamentalOperationalData_Soviet m_FODSystemSoviet;
        FundamentalOperationalData_RRB m_FODSystemRRB;
    };

public:

    static const KUINT16 FUNDAMENTAL_OPERATIONAL_DATA_SIZE = 16;

    FundamentalOperationalData( void );

    FundamentalOperationalData( KDataStream & stream ) throw( KException );

    FundamentalOperationalData( const FundamentalOperationalData_MarkXTransponder & FOD );

    FundamentalOperationalData( const FundamentalOperationalData_MarkXInterrogator & FOD );

    FundamentalOperationalData( const FundamentalOperationalData_Soviet & FOD );

    FundamentalOperationalData( const FundamentalOperationalData_RRB & FOD );

    virtual ~FundamentalOperationalData( void );

    //************************************
    // FullName:    KDIS::DATA_TYPE::FundamentalOperationalData::SetFundamentalOperationalData
    //              KDIS::DATA_TYPE::FundamentalOperationalData::GetFundamentalOperationalData
    // Description: Sets/Gets Fundamental Operational Data for a specific system.
    // Parameter:   FundamentalOperationalData_X FOD
    //************************************
    void SetFundamentalOperationalData_MarkXTransponder( const FundamentalOperationalData_MarkXTransponder & FOD );
    void SetFundamentalOperationalData_MarkXInterrogator( const FundamentalOperationalData_MarkXInterrogator & FOD );
    void SetFundamentalOperationalData_Soviet( const FundamentalOperationalData_Soviet & FOD );
    void SetFundamentalOperationalData_RRB( const FundamentalOperationalData_RRB & FOD );
    const FundamentalOperationalData_MarkXTransponder & GetSetFundamentalOperationalData_MarkXTransponder() const;
    FundamentalOperationalData_MarkXTransponder & GetSetFundamentalOperationalData_MarkXTransponder();
    const FundamentalOperationalData_MarkXInterrogator & GetFundamentalOperationalData_MarkXInterrogator() const;
    FundamentalOperationalData_MarkXInterrogator & GetFundamentalOperationalData_MarkXInterrogator();
    const FundamentalOperationalData_Soviet & GetFundamentalOperationalData_Soviet() const;
    FundamentalOperationalData_Soviet & GetFundamentalOperationalData_Soviet();
    const FundamentalOperationalData_RRB & GetFundamentalOperationalData_RRB() const;
    FundamentalOperationalData_RRB & GetFundamentalOperationalData_RRB();

    //************************************
    // FullName:    KDIS::DATA_TYPE::FundamentalOperationalData::GetAsString
    // Description: Returns a string representation
    //************************************
    virtual KString GetAsString() const;

    //************************************
    // FullName:    KDIS::DATA_TYPE::FundamentalOperationalData::Decode
    // Description: Convert From Network Data.
    // Parameter:   KDataStream & stream
    //************************************
    virtual void Decode( KDataStream & stream ) throw( KException );

    //************************************
    // FullName:    KDIS::DATA_TYPE::FundamentalOperationalData::Encode
    // Description: Convert To Network Data.
    // Parameter:   KDataStream & stream
    //************************************
    virtual KDataStream Encode() const;
    virtual void Encode( KDataStream & stream ) const;

    KBOOL operator == ( const FundamentalOperationalData & Value ) const;
    KBOOL operator != ( const FundamentalOperationalData & Value ) const;
};

}; // END namespace DATA_TYPES
}; // END namespace KDIS
```

Comment: What stops you from doing the " declare something as FundamentalOperationalData Mydata(1,2,3..."? Do you get errors? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

`FundamentalOperationalData` has no constructor that takes `(1,2,3..`

You can initialize this class with:

- *default constructor*
- `FundamentalOperationalData_MarkXTransponder` reference
- `FundamentalOperationalData_MarkXInterrogator` reference
- `FundamentalOperationalData_Soviet` reference
- `FundamentalOperationalData_RRB` reference
- or a `KDataStream` reference

`FundamentalOperationalData_MarkXTransponder` is a protected member of the `FundamentalOperationalData` class.

The `union` here is to give access to *these members*:

```
    struct
    {
        KUINT8 m_ui8SystemStatus;
        KUINT8 m_ui8AltParam4;
        KUINT8 m_ui8InfoLayers;
        KUINT8 m_ui8Modifier;
        KUINT16 m_ui16Param1;
        KUINT16 m_ui16Param2;
        KUINT16 m_ui16Param3;
        KUINT16 m_ui16Param4;
        KUINT16 m_ui16Param5;
        KUINT16 m_ui16Param6;
    };
```

Through *these members*

```
    FundamentalOperationalData_MarkXTransponder m_FODSystemMarkTransponder;
    FundamentalOperationalData_MarkXInterrogator m_FODSystemMarkInterrogator;
    FundamentalOperationalData_Soviet m_FODSystemSoviet;
    FundamentalOperationalData_RRB m_FODSystemRRB;
```

As the union only has **enough storage to hold the largest member in its member-list.**

Comment: FundamentalOperationalData_MarkXTransponder is a protected member of the FundamentalOperationalData class. So the why is there an union of FundamtalOperationalData_MarkXTransponder and an struct?